# can't find a function from loaded package

Tags: r, lazyeval

I created a local package with personal functions to be easily used within R. One of these is aimed to be used in the `lidR` package within a wrapper function (i.e. `grid_metrics`). For this reason I took the scheme of [this script](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/blob/master/R/utils_metrics.R) as a reference, exporting both the long name (e.g. `my_metrics(param1, param2,...)`) and the lazy one (e.g. `.my_metrics`), because I really like its ease of use.

Nevertheless, if I load my package and then call the lazy function

```
library(mypackage)
test = grid_metrics(las, .my_metrics, 20)
```

it does not work, so I have to load in memory the function by running its code from the file. At this stage, I can use it in both forms.

Within the NAMESPACE file I can see that both forms are exported so my last guess is that this might be related somehow to `lazyeval` but I don't get how.

Comment: Do you see the function in the output of `ls("package:mypackage")` after loading the package?

Comment: yes, I see it with the general name (i.e. my_metrics)

Comment: Have you `@export`ed your function when creating the package? In case if you made your package with `roxygen2`.

Comment: Maybe stupid comment, but the names differ between ```grid_metrics```and what you provided in your example ( ```gridmetrics```)

Comment: yes I did @andschar and no, that was just a typo @ elielink :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is related to the `DESCRIPTION` section in which the `lidR` package was included. Since when I moved from `Imports` to `Depends` the issue is solved.